# Why the probability characteristic function is always exist but moment generation function is not always exist?

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions, moment-generating-functions

I know that the characteristic function is always exist and moment generation function is not always exist instantly but don't know exactly mathematically.

Comment: Short version: $e^{itX}$ is a bounded random variable (its modulus is surely 1) so its expectation always exists.  $e^{tX}$ may be unbounded so its expectation might not exist.

Comment: I doubt there is more to it than @Nate's short version.